# Running a Secondary Thread for Output in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I’m looking for a portable method for creating threads specifically for output of data in C++. I’d prefer to stay away from Boost if possible, but I’m not against using it if it’s the best option.

Here is the situation:
I have a program that does a complex computation on some data that it reads and produces three output streams with a large amount of textual data. These three streams are being compressed on the fly using the Bzip2 library.
What I would like to do is to have the main computation run in the main thread, while the compression and output of the data is done in three additional threads. The idea being that in this way I can utilise the available computing cores and eliminate any bottleneck that the Bzip2 compression may be causing to the actual processing.

The way I imagine this working is for the three output threads to have open output file streams and to be waiting for string data that will then be compressed and output. The main thread will run its computation sending output to the other threads when necessary. Obviously, adequate buffering will have to be designed, but that’s not a problem.

I’d appreciate any suggestions regarding the best way to tackle this problem, in particular, what C++ libraries are the most appropriate for the task at hand. Keep in mind, that I would like to handle the buffering in the output threads and they should receive string class data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to stay away from boost. Is it venomous or something?

Comment: In addition to boost, there's Apache Portable Runtime, which is a much smaller dependency (less than 1MB source download).

Comment: boost is one of the best C++ libraries available and the C++0x threads I believe were partially modeled on what was done in boost.

Comment: @Eli: And the problem with that is?  It's fully compatible with C++, and it will compile MUCH faster.

Comment: @Ben: I just wasn't aware that it's fully C++ compatible. Oftentimes a C++ library is better for C++ because it's more in the application's domain (i.e. uses exceptions, C++-like memory management, etc)

Comment: @Eli: In any halfway decent API, memory management inside the library is completely abstracted away from the library user.  At that point, it scarcely matters whether it uses `malloc` or `new`.  C libraries that aren't C++ compatible are few and far between, this is the primary reason C++ is as popular as it is.  Now, some things are very object-oriented in nature and really benefit from a C++ rewrite.  For threads, though, the benefits are minimal (ok a C++ library saves you having to cast your thread context to a class pointer, big deal).

Comment: @Ben: a couple of examples of C++-oriented thread-library design: (1) thread as a class you can inherit from, thus implementing your threads in a relatively clean way. (2) synchronization primitives like mutexes which benefit very much from C++-style construction and destruction, allowing to lock a mutex and let the destructor worry about its unlocking

Comment: @Eli: That's true.  I was thinking of threading as a separate topic from mutexes (for example, it's perfectly feasible to use a message-passing architecture, all synchronization primitives are buried deep inside the threading library).

Comment: @Ben: there are other examples. My point is simply that if you program in C++, well designed *C++* libraries are more convenient to use than *C* libraries. This is not to say, of course, that good *C* libraries should never be used in C++ programs, so your initial input on the possibility to use APR is sound (although personally I would use Boost instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't support threads in its standard (at least not now), and to have threads portably you must use some library. There are *many* C++ libraries giving you portable threads out there, and your particular problem doesn't seem special in any way. Boost is very well received and adopted and has the best chance to influence future versions of the C++ standard. It is efficient and portable, so why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the Boost.Thread library.  It is well documented, tested and light-weight (compared to full-featured libraries with multi-platform threading support, such as Qt).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Boost ASIO: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html

It's very flexible in terms of threading organization. As a matter of fact you may re-think your design and get rid of additional threads at all. But it also supports your idea as well.